# How to do iPhone notification without internet?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am now using an calendar app, it allow me to set a reminder and it reminds me even I am at Airplane mode.

How can I do the same thing in my program?

Comment: Why do you think setting a calendar alert and reminding would require internet unless you are sync an external calendar?

Comment: You can simply use location notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use UILocalNotifications,
here is the url
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Your calendar alert is a `local notification` set on your device. It isn't a `push notification` to require internet connection.

Refer the examples of notification usage [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW11)